# Require a list of a certain type in mypy

Tags: python, typing, mypy

Let's say I have a function that can only take a list of strings, like the following:

```
from typing import List


def iter_lower(lst: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    new_lst = []
    for string in lst:
        new_lst.append(string.lower())
    return new_lst

lst: List = ["Hello", "World", 1]
iter_lower(lst)
```

`mypy` does not complain about this, even though it is clearly wrong since `lst` is a generic list, containing an integer which is incompatible with `.lower()`.  Is there some hint I could use in the argument list of `iter_lower` that will cause `mypy` to reject this usage?

Comment: If you wanted type checking, you shouldn't have used `List` as a type hint. You specifically disabled the checks you want.

Comment: Is there a way to express, for example, the items in the list are a union of every type?.  I see for example that the annotation `List[Union[int, str]]` is correctly caught.

Comment: `List[object]`.

Comment: Thank you!  Leave that as an answer and I will accept it, if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `List` type hint. Without a type parameter, this is interpreted as `List[Any]`, disabling the checks you wanted. (`Any` is basically the "don't check me" type.)

If you want mypy to treat `lst` as "list of arbitrarily mixed types, with type checking", you should use `List[object]`.